# Either or type but not null

Tags: typescript

I am having issue with typescript when using or operator it is accepting null value as well which I don't want:

```
interface Value1 {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}
interface Value2 {
  id: string;
  image: string;
}
```

Now, when using it:

```
val: Value1 | Value2
```

It should accept either Value1 or Value2 but it's also accepting null value. If I just do `val: Value1` then doesn't accept null. So, how to avoid null value when using or operator?

Comment: Can you create a minimal example on a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.5.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDYFcIEZkDeAUMsiHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDcJyEFcwGtDTEGyIBfIqEixEKdNggAmQh2AATfoxbtSwbsxr0NQ9mKIIA9iAbIKAT1k5a9vMgA+aTDkUBeMlgwYiIA) because your code does seems to error as I would expect it to.

Comment: You need to enable [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#strictnullchecks). There must be an original question I can point to for this... *Edit:* I can't find a clean one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. But isn't it possible or workaround without enabling that?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar - I don't know for sure and I'm not a TypeScript expert, but I don't think you can. And you may have some friction when you first enable it because `null` and `undefined` creep into things a lot more often than you might expect. But IMHO it's worth it, because...`null` and `undefined` creep into things a lot more than you might expect. :-D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `null` and `undefined` are assignable to any type. You need to enable [`strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#strictnullchecks) to prevent that:

> By default, values like `null` and `undefined` are assignable to any other type. This can make writing some code easier, but forgetting to handle `null` and `undefined` is the cause of countless bugs in the world - some consider it a [billion dollar mistake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybrQvs4x0Ps)! The `strictNullChecks` flag makes handling `null` and `undefined` more explicit, and spares us from worrying about whether we forgot to handle `null` and `undefined`.

Comment: I have tried enabling it. But I am getting another error. For eg. when I have `SomeValue | null` it states `Type 'SomeValue | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'SomeValue | null'`. So, I have to modify in multiple places. I would be glad if we could have some workaround without enabling it.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar - It sounds like you're trying to assign something with a type that includes `undefined` (an optional property or parameter, perhaps?) to something that doesn't allow `undefined` (although it allows `null`). With strict checks, you can't do that.

Comment: (Side note: That "billion dollar mistake" thing always bothers me. I'm quite sure that if the guy hadn't come up with NULL, whatever he came up with instead would have been just as problematic and/or someone else would have come up with it. :-) )